# Helvet font on pdflatex under FreeBSD?

Tags: pdftex

This template is not producing anything on FreeBSD, but ok on Linux. How would it be possible to fix this on FreeBSD?
It must work but it seems that TeXLive with PDFLATEX is buggy.

Can it be possible to have a code that produce helvet as well on FreeBSD?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what version of texlive are you using? And exactly what error are you getting

Comment: it can not simply not produce anything, it must produce output or a warning message. Do you have the package installed?

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: there is not clear post message, observed. The systems are 12 and 13 FreeBSD.